# Making all instances in a string 5 or less characters

Tags: r, string

I am trying to make all of the words in this data 5 characters or less.

```
data <- "The prisoner and his friend escaped but were later caught"
```

Everything that I have tried is only allowing me to take the same number of characters off of each term, but I am wanting to only take enough off of each to

The result I am looking for is:

```
The priso and his frien escap but were later caugh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(data, "\\b(\\S{5})\\S+\\b", "\\1")
[1] "The priso and his frien escap but were later caugh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `strsplit` function and the `stringr` package. Essentially, we break the string into a character vector, then subset each element in the vector to the first five characters:

```r
data |>
  # Separate string into a vector
  strsplit(split = " ") |>
  # Unlist so we are just left with a vector
  unlist() |>
  # Subset each element in the vector to the first 5 elements.
  stringr::str_sub(1, 5) |>
  # rejoin all words with a space.
  paste(collapse = " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

data <- "The prisoner and his friend escaped but were later caught"

data |>
  str_split(" ") |> 
  unlist() |> 
  map_chr(str_sub, end = 5) |> 
  paste(collapse = " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub` and match 5 non white spaces `\\S{5}` and store them in `\\1` by placing brackets around and match every following non white space with `\\S+` which will be removed.

```
gsub("(\\S{5})\\S+", "\\1", data)
#[1] "The priso and his frien escap but were later caugh"
```